# What is wrong in the below code of input validation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I have trying to validate an input text field, which should contain only characters. I am using test() here. Ideally it should return true when the field is given string like "rent" but in every case it is going for the false scenario. Can someone please suggest why it is happening. I have tried debugging and found out that the values are coming fine in if statement. Please help.

```
    const [text,setText] = useState(" ")
    const [amount,setAmount] = useState(0)
  
    const {addTransaction} = useContext(GlobalContext)
    console.log(text,amount)


   const onSubmit = e =>{
   e.preventDefault(); 
   var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  
   if(letters.test(text)){
   const newTransantion = {
   id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000),
   text:text,
   amount:+amount
   } 
   addTransaction(newTransantion)
  }
  else{
    alert('Please give the correct input')
  }
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to see where the error is without the full example. Especially need to know where `setText` is called. if it's somehow called on the other end of the `addTransaction` function, then the default string `" "` will never pass your regex, and the text will never be updated..

Answer (score 0):

I think the regex test function is working properly.
Here is a sample. I would insert some debug prints around the code.

```js
var text = ["hello", "world", "4rent",
 "Howdy", "Buy", " spaces oh ", "99Bb"];

// Validation regex
var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;

// Test validate our array values
//
for (const element of text) 
   if ( letters.test( element ) ) 
      console.log( element + " - passed" );
   else
      console.log( element + " - failed" );

console.log( "\n\n\n" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, that in the onSubmit function , the state variable "text" is empty string all the time.

Does the input text field (we do not see here) have an onChange attribute?? which should be a function updating the "text" state after every stroke.